# Is there still a reason to null htmlElement reference?

Tags: javascript, dom

For the longest time, we did use something like:

```
class MyElementWrapper {
  el: HTMLElement;

  constructor(html: string) {
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.el.innerHTML = html;
  }

  destroy() {
    this.el.parentElement.removeChild(this.el)
    this.el = null;
  }
}
```

Is the `el = null` part still necessary if we don't play to use the class instance anyway?

Comment: If you're going to be disposing of the class instance, then there shouldn't be a need. But if you keep a reference to it, then you also keep the element in scope and thus it takes up memory.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't plan to use the instance, there might be references to it hanging around in other variables, so they'll keep it from becoming garbage, and that will keep the DOM element from becoming garbage. If you've logged the instance to the console, it keeps a live reference to it.

Comment: True, but if the instance is referenced there is a memory leak, in its own... If I recall the GB is "mark-and-sweep" thus able to clean all of this.

Comment: When programming in languages with automatic memory management, it's easy to lose track.